# Mass updating a line in a text file

Tags: awk, sed

I am looking for a one-liner (ideally) to change all instances of:

```
# dropped packets chart for kvm890.0 = auto
```

to

```
dropped packets chart for kvm890.0 = no
```

I should note that "kvm890.0" varies, for example like so:

```
# dropped packets chart for kvm508.0 = auto
# dropped packets chart for kvm864.0 = auto
# dropped packets chart for kvm357.0 = auto
# dropped packets chart for kvm822.0 = auto
# dropped packets chart for kvm785.0 = auto
```

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO, On SO we do encourage users to add their efforts which they have put in order to solve their own problems so please do add them in your question and let us know then.

Comment: Hi, if any of the answers from below helped you in any way, please accept and or upvote it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just use sed:

```
sed -i 's/STRING_TO_REPLACE/NEW_STRING/g' filename
```

Answer (score 0):

Break the string in two parts, capture the known part in the first group(`\1`) and replace everything else with string `no`.

```
sed  's/\(dropped packets chart for.*= \).*/\1no/g' textfile
# dropped packets chart for kvm508.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm864.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm357.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm822.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm785.0 = no
```

OR

Here, just change all the `auto` to `no` when `dropped packets chart for` string is present in the line.

```
sed '/dropped packets chart for/ s/\<auto\>/no/g' textfile
# dropped packets chart for kvm508.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm864.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm357.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm822.0 = no
# dropped packets chart for kvm785.0 = no
```